# ASP.NET development in Win 7

Tags: asp.net, windows-7

I just got a Win 7 machine at work, and am wondering if there is anyway I can use multiple website feature (IIS 6) while programming instead of using the default website all the time ?

Basically I want to treat my Win 7 box as a server box but I should have the flexibility to create websites and develop against them. Like I could be working on a version of msn.com site, and i want to access it as msn.com while development but not go to the real msn.com site.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recomendation is to Hyper-V and just create a virtual to play around with that has those specifications you desire.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the host file, add this line

127.0.0.1 msn.com

Comment: and this is probably the easiest way too unless you have some desire to turn off "development mode" and visit the real site